# A question on regular space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a regular space and for $x\in X$ there exist open sets $U_n$ in $X$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$, such that $x\in U_n$. How can we may assume that $x\in \overline{U_{n+1}}\subset U_n$, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$  ?

Comment: Are the $U_n$'s supposed to have any particular property (other than the one listed)?

Comment: No. i tried to do this by use this fact that for every $G_\delta$-set there is a non-incresaing sequence $\{G_i\}$ of open sets such that $x\in \bigcap U_n=\bigcap G_i$ and definition of regular space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This rests on the "open neighbourhoods" characterisation of regularity:

> **Fact:** A topological space $X$ is regular iff for each $x \in X$ and each open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ there is an open neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ with $\overline{V} \subseteq U$.

So suppose $\langle U_n \rangle_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of open neighbourhoods of $x \in X$.  We inductively construct a sequence $\langle V_n \rangle_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of open neighbourhoods of $x$ such that $V_n \subseteq U_n$ and $\overline{V_{n+1}} \subseteq V_n$ as follows:

- $V_0 = U_0$.
- Note that $V_n \cap U_{n+1}$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$, and so by regularity there is an open neighbourhood $V_{n+1}$ of $x$ such that $\overline{V_{n+1}} \subseteq V_n \cap U_{n+1} \subseteq V_n$.